# CSS Reversed Transitions Order

Tags: html, css, transition

I don't know if this question has been asked before, but wherever I looked, the answer wasn't helpful.  What I'm trying to do is move text away and then lift up a gray box, and when I move my mouse away from the gray box, the gray box goes down first, and then the text moves back.  With my code, the text moves back first, which doesn't look good.  Is there a way to reverse the transition order when reverting back to normal?  Here is my CSS:

```
.doge{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#c6a65f 70%,#cbc595 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-position: left;
    transition: 1.6s;


}
.dogediv{
    width: 537px;
    height: 529px;
    background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg");
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 5s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
.div2:hover > .doge{
    transform: translateX(550px);
}
.div2:hover {
    height: 10px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home of the Doge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="dogediv">
        <div class="div2" style="background-color: gray">
            <h1 class="doge">Welcome to the Home of the Doge</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you provide your html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add transition-delay:1s on class "doge" and transition-delay:0.5s on div2.

```css
.doge{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#c6a65f 70%,#cbc595 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-position: left;
    transition: 1.6s;
   transition-delay: 1s;


}
.dogediv{
    width: 537px;
    height: 529px;
    background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg");
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 3s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.div2:hover {
    height: 10px; 
}
.div2:hover > .doge{
    transform: translateX(550px);
transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dogediv">
        <div class="div2" style="background-color: gray">
            <h1 class="doge">Welcome to the Home of the Doge</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

May this help you.

Comment: Note that if you use transition delay on .doge class it will apply both in its normal state and in its hover state, making the transition start 1s after the  mouseenter. You can add transition-delay: 0s in .div2:hover > .doge to prevent this.

Comment: when adding in hover it's not work proper.That's why i do like that.